# Mac wifi passwords are being stored in System Keychain, not iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, wifi, security, password, keychain

I'd like my wifi passwords to be available across my Apple devices.  But my Mac is storing wifi passwords in the System Keychain, not the iCloud keychain.  That means they're not automatically shared with my iPhone.

I've double-checked that iCloud Keychain is turned on for my Mac.  iCloud Keychain does show some wifi passwords, and recent passwords have been saved both to iCloud and System.  I believe though that this is because my iPhone is saving to iCloud, so if I connect to a network with that device then iCloud Keychain will have the password.

How can I change the default Mac wifi password storage location to iCloud Keychain?